# Configure custom template for Sonata Admin bundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I have created a custom template for `create` action, I tried to configure it as mentioned in the documentation:

```
article.admin.article:
    class: ArticleBundle\Admin\ArticleAdmin
    arguments: [~, ArticleBundle\Entity\Article, "ArticleBundle:ArticleAdmin"]
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: admin, label: Article }
    calls:
        - [ setTemplate, [create, "ArticleBundle:ArticleAdmin:ArticleBundle"]]
```

My new **create.html.twig** template is in directory: `src\ArticleBundle\Resources\views\ArticleAdmin\ArticleBundle`

When I load create page I still get the default template, not the one I configured.

What can be wrong?

Comment: have you cleared cache ? e.g. in prod enviroment: `php app/console --env=prod cache:clear`

Comment: already tried to clear the cache but same problem

Comment: i found that there is no **create** template , it's the edit template who is used for both create and edit action , so how can i have differents templates , one for create and the other for edit ?

Comment: I have the same error

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
group: admin, label: Article
```

you are missing double quotes. Should be:

```
group: "admin", label: "Article"
```

The call for `setTemplate` should be:

```
calls:
    - [ setTemplate, [create, "ArticleBundle:ArticleAdmin:ArticleBundle/create.html.twig"]]
```

See Sonata Admin [templates](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/templates.html) reference.